# How to Import 3rd party Python Library on IronPython Library in ASP.net

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, ironpython

I have a function that executes a python script. The python script calls the jira library to connect to it's server. Then it will return data and will create an excel file for it.  The python script is running ok when I executed manually, but the problem is when I call it on my asp function it returns error

> there are no module name jira

I guess IronPython doesn't have library for jira because I just installed it on Python Library.

I even try to execute the script thru Process and it was triggered but unfortunately it doesn't return anything.

here is my code for executing a python thru IronPython

```
 ScriptRuntimeSetup setup = Python.CreateRuntimeSetup(null);
        ScriptRuntime runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.GetEngine(runtime);
        var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
        paths.Add(@"C:\Users\jdecena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib");
        engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
        ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("C:/Dave/jirautomatic/try.py");
        ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
        source.Execute(scope);
        dynamic Generate = scope.GetVariable("connect_to_jira_and_get_projects");
        dynamic gen = Generate();
        gen();
```

and here is my code executing python thru process

```
Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Dave\jirautomatic\try.py";            
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        proc.Dispose();
```

Is there a way that I can include the Library on Python to IronPython?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

It is common problem when you are executing the python through c# or ASP.NET. Only the reason is C# expect all binaries in the form of assembly where python expects in the form of modules.

For this problem, two methods are available

#### Setting path in system variables

It is the simple is the simple way to set the modules into system variables. once the process started, then python will automatically search for the system path. either you can directly set the path in **PATH** variable or you can create new variable called **PYTHONPATH**

#### Setting path at runtime

This kind of approach is to set only for the life time of the application. for example, if any application want to use the 'known' module which are available in the project, then it can set the path runtime using **sys** module in python. But remember that once the program is executed, then the temporary variables will be lost. so this kind of code can be available either in c# or in python. use System.IO namespace in c# or sys module in Python

Comment: Hi, Can you give me example regarding this?
Is GetSearchParth and SetSearchPath not enough?

Comment: Hi, this link might help you to set variable for your process [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553830/set-environment-variable-for-process)