# Call .bashrc for a C# process call

Tags: c#, bash, process, subprocess, environment-variables

So I want to call my .bashrc file for a subprocess in C# to setup some environment variables. I looked at this [Set environment variables for a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553830/set-environment-variable-for-process) but is there a simple way to call the .bashrc file for my subprocess without going through and setting all of my environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

The `.bashrc` file is meaningless and useless unless the subprocess you are running is, in fact, `bash`.  However, inasmuch as `bash` may indeed be launched if your executable is a shell script, and inasmuch as you can always write a wrapper script around the real intended executable, and inasmuch as you can use `bash`'s `-c` option to run any other command via `bash`, putting `bash` in the loop isn't a big problem.  (That supposes, of course, that you're running on a system that *has* `bash`.  I don't necessarily assume that when the host program is in C#.)

Having one way or another gotten `bash` into the loop, [your options](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) are to read `.bashrc` explicitly via the `.` or `source` command, to pass the `-i` option to `bash`, or to name `.bashrc` via the environment variable `BASH_ENV`.  Any of these will cause `bash` to read commands from your `.basrc`, including those setting environment variables.