# How can I run a long string in a Start.Process

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to run

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe" -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmn128M -Xmx31497M -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -Djava.library.path=C:\JHMC\versions\1.15.2\natives -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.0.1003 -cp C:\JHMC\libraries\org\tlauncher\tl_skin_cape_1.15.2\1.8\tl_skin_cape_1.15.2-1.8.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\6.2\asm-tree-6.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm\6.2\asm-6.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\6.2\asm-commons-6.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\minecraft\launchwrapper\1.12\launchwrapper-1.12.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\tlauncher\patchy\1.1\patchy-1.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\mojang\javabridge\1.0.22\javabridge-1.0.22.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.25.Final\netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\mojang\brigadier\1.0.17\brigadier-1.0.17.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\mojang\datafixerupper\2.0.24\datafixerupper-2.0.24.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\tlauncher\authlib\1.6.25\authlib-1.6.25.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\8.2.1\fastutil-8.2.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\3.2.2\lwjgl-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-jemalloc\3.2.2\lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-openal\3.2.2\lwjgl-openal-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-opengl\3.2.2\lwjgl-opengl-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-glfw\3.2.2\lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-stb\3.2.2\lwjgl-stb-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-tinyfd\3.2.2\lwjgl-tinyfd-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.11.3\text2speech-1.11.3.jar;C:\JHMC\versions\1.15.2\1.15.2.jar -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C:\JHMC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true org.tlauncher.LaunchNew --username Emilo --version 1.15.2 --gameDir C:\JHMC --assetsDir C:\JHMC\assets --assetIndex 1.15 --uuid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --accessToken null --userType legacy --versionType release --width 925 --height 530 --tweakClass org.tlauncher.tweaker.Tweaker

in visual basic using a button but i cant get it to work since there's a lot of conflicting stuff in that command and visual studio gets confused.

here is my code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim strGreeting As String
  Dim strName As String
  strName = TextBox1.Text
  strGreeting = "Hello " & strName
  MessageBox.Show(strGreeting)

  Process.Start("CMD", "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe" - Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack = True - Xmn128M - Xmx31497M - XX: HeapDumpPath = MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump - Xss1M - Djava.library.path = C : \JHMC\versions\1.15.2\natives -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.0.1003 -cp C:\JHMC\libraries\org\tlauncher\tl_skin_cape_1.15.2\1.8\tl_skin_cape_1.15.2-1.8.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\6.2\asm-tree-6.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm\6.2\asm-6.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\6.2\asm-commons-6.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\minecraft\launchwrapper\1.12\launchwrapper-1.12.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\tlauncher\patchy\1.1\patchy-1.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\mojang\javabridge\1.0.22\javabridge-1.0.22.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.25.Final\netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\mojang\brigadier\1.0.17\brigadier-1.0.17.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\mojang\datafixerupper\2.0.24\datafixerupper-2.0.24.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\tlauncher\authlib\1.6.25\authlib-1.6.25.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\8.2.1\fastutil-8.2.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\3.2.2\lwjgl-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-jemalloc\3.2.2\lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-openal\3.2.2\lwjgl-openal-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-opengl\3.2.2\lwjgl-opengl-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-glfw\3.2.2\lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-stb\3.2.2\lwjgl-stb-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-tinyfd\3.2.2\lwjgl-tinyfd-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.11.3\text2speech-1.11.3.jar;C:\JHMC\versions\1.15.2\1.15.2.jar -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C:\JHMC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent = 20 - XX : G1ReservePercent = 20 - XX : MaxGCPauseMillis = 50 - XX : G1HeapRegionSize = 32M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=True -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=True org.tlauncher.LaunchNew --username Emilo --version 1.15.2 --gameDir C:\JHMC --assetsDir C:\JHMC\assets --assetIndex 1.15 --uuid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --accessToken null --userType legacy --versionType release --width 925 --height 530 --tweakClass org.tlauncher.tweaker.Tweaker)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This doesn't show us the errors or the code you have.  Update your question.

Comment: Would it perhaps be simpler to set a CLASSPATH environment variable for the process you launch? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553830/set-environment-variables-for-a-process

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: Yeah, you kinda need to put those arguments INSIDE a string. Visual Studio is "getting confused" because all that argument string has been pasted in without `" "` so it thinks it's VB.NET (and it's not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like:

```
Dim startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()


startInfo.EnvironmentVariables("CLASSPATH") = "C:\JHMC\libraries\org\tlauncher\tl_skin_cape_1.15.2\1.8\tl_skin_cape_1.15.2-1.8.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-tree\6.2\asm-tree-6.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm\6.2\asm-6.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\ow2\asm\asm-commons\6.2\asm-commons-6.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\minecraft\launchwrapper\1.12\launchwrapper-1.12.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\tlauncher\patchy\1.1\patchy-1.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\oshi-project\oshi-core\1.1\oshi-core-1.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\jna\4.4.0\jna-4.4.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\mojang\javabridge\1.0.22\javabridge-1.0.22.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\5.0.3\jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.1.25.Final\netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\21.0\guava-21.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.5\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.5\commons-io-2.5.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\mojang\brigadier\1.0.17\brigadier-1.0.17.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\mojang\datafixerupper\2.0.24\datafixerupper-2.0.24.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.0\gson-2.8.0.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\tlauncher\authlib\1.6.25\authlib-1.6.25.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\it\unimi\dsi\fastutil\8.2.1\fastutil-8.2.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.8.1\log4j-api-2.8.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.8.1\log4j-core-2.8.1.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\3.2.2\lwjgl-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-jemalloc\3.2.2\lwjgl-jemalloc-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-openal\3.2.2\lwjgl-openal-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-opengl\3.2.2\lwjgl-opengl-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-glfw\3.2.2\lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-stb\3.2.2\lwjgl-stb-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl-tinyfd\3.2.2\lwjgl-tinyfd-3.2.2.jar;C:\JHMC\libraries\com\mojang\text2speech\1.11.3\text2speech-1.11.3.jar;C:\JHMC\versions\1.15.2\1.15.2.jar"

// Required for EnvironmentVariables to be set
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false

startInfo.FileName = "javaw.exe"

startInfo.Arguments = "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmn128M -Xmx31497M -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xss1M -Djava.library.path=C:\JHMC\versions\1.15.2\natives -Dminecraft.launcher.brand=minecraft-launcher -Dminecraft.launcher.version=2.0.1003 -Dminecraft.applet.TargetDirectory=C:\JHMC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M -Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true org.tlauncher.LaunchNew --username Emilo --version 1.15.2 --gameDir C:\JHMC --assetsDir C:\JHMC\assets --assetIndex 1.15 --uuid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --accessToken null --userType legacy --versionType release --width 925 --height 530 --tweakClass org.tlauncher.tweaker.Tweaker"

Process.Start(startInfo)
```